# improving applicativeNel validation when result should have the value or nothing

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I am currently learning to use ArrowKT and I have the following code for validating an input. I tried to collect all the errors at once and execute the validations in parallel since most of them are done against the database.

```
return Validated.applicativeNel<ValidationError>()
    .tupledN(
        validateA(input).toValidatedNel(),
        validateB(input).toValidatedNel(),
        validateC(input).toValidatedNel(),
        validateSlotIsFree(input).toValidatedNel(),
    )
    .fix()
    .map { (a, b, c, _) ->
        ...
    }

private suspend fun validateSlotIsFree(input: CreateDto): Validated<ValidationError.SlotUnavailable, Boolean> {
    val exists = appointmentRepository.existsBy...()
    return if (exists) true.valid() else ValidationError.SlotUnavailable.invalid()
}
```

Is there any better way to handle the validation inside `validateSlotIsFree`? It looks like I am forced to return something on the right side in case of valid but I would not want to. I was looking for something like an `Option` where the value would be the Error and empty would mean that the validation has passed. The problem with this is that `Validated.fromOption(...)` would take the value and apply it to the Right and I need the opposite.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/

Comment: Why use `Boolean` when you have `Unit`? In any case, `validated.fold({ it.some() }, Option::none)` should do the trick.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK thanks for the article, much useful perspective there; although I wouldn't help in my case because I still need to collect that error.
@MLProgrammer-CiM I guess the APIs do not allow me to do it that way. I tried using `Validated<Error, Nothing>` and `Either<Error, Nothing>` but I don't know to resolve the `Nothing` case since the API for `Valid(A)` and `Right(A)` expects a non nullable object.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM it looks like I misunderstood your suggestion. I made it work with Unit

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers of both @LordRaydenMK and @MLProgrammer-CiM I found two solutions

```
private suspend fun validateSlotIsFree(input: CreateAppointmentDto): Validated<ValidationError.SlotUnavailable, Unit> {
    val exists = appointmentRepository.existsBy...()
    return if (exists) Valid(Unit) else ValidationError.SlotUnavailable.invalid()
}
```

Previously I have tried with `Nothing` and it didn't work. The reason for that is that `Nothing` has no possible value and that is why using `null` didn't work. In order for it to work with `null` I had to use `Nothing?`.

The first solution is preferred since using `Nothing?` would be incorrect because it actually says that this function does not return anything and at the same time it can return `null`.